# Civicase report shows empty list

Tags: wordpress, civireport, civicase

I have set up report to list the number of active cases, however the report doesn't show anything when I refresh results, even though there is a number of opened cases which show in the Case dashboard.

Any idea why this might be not working?

I am running version 5.13.1 on Wordpress

[image: CiviCase report settings]

---

I added the code for the report (Developer Tab)

```
Class used: CRM_Report_Form_Case_Summary

SQL Modes: NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS c2_civireport.sort_name as civicrm_c2_client_name, c2_civireport.id as civicrm_c2_id, case_civireport.id as civicrm_case_id, case_civireport.subject as civicrm_case_subject, case_civireport.status_id as civicrm_case_status_id, case_civireport.start_date as civicrm_case_start_date, case_civireport.end_date as civicrm_case_end_date, IF(case_civireport.end_date Is Null, '', DATEDIFF(case_civireport.end_date, case_civireport.start_date)) as civicrm_case_duration  


FROM civicrm_contact contact_civireport
inner join civicrm_relationship relationship_civireport on contact_civireport.id = relationship_civireport.contact_id_b
inner join civicrm_case case_civireport on case_civireport.id = relationship_civireport.case_id
inner join civicrm_relationship_type relationship_type_civireport on relationship_type_civireport.id=relationship_civireport.relationship_type_id
inner join civicrm_case_contact case_contact_civireport on case_contact_civireport.case_id = case_civireport.id
inner join civicrm_contact c2_civireport on c2_civireport.id=case_contact_civireport.contact_id


WHERE case_civireport.case_type_id  REGEXP '[[:cntrl:]]*3[[:cntrl:]]*' AND ( case_civireport.status_id IN (1, 3) ) AND ( case_civireport.is_deleted = 0 )   

ORDER BY case_civireport.start_date ASC  

LIMIT 0, 50
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a screenshot of which report and what the filters are?

Comment: I've added the case summary report settings which I am trying to use - are are set to defaults and no filters are applied

Comment: Thanks - have added a possible answer.

Comment: Looking at number of tabs available to your user, it might be Contact Access/ permission issue.

Comment: @SunilPawar I'm not sure it's permissions because that's what the tabs look like when you first create a new report from a template before you've saved it as an instance. Also he says the dashboard shows the cases.

Comment: So this is definitely not a permission problem as I am the database administrator and I should be able to see the permissions. The only other thing worth adding is that I changed the domain address for the website. I updated all the details (so I hope) and other features seem to be working without big problems.

Comment: The SQL you added suggests you are filtering on case type. Is it maybe a disabled type or something like that?

Comment: Nope, I have the same problem even if I disable all filters. I can also see these cases without any problem in my CiviCase Dashboard

Comment: If you run that query in mysql directly, via phpmyadmin or some other way, does it return any data?

Comment: I get the following message when I execute the query in phpmyadmin: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

Comment: How are the roles and relationship types configured in your system? On a manage case screen for example do you see anything in the Roles section? And for your case type definitions do you have roles defined?

Comment: Interesting... I can only see the cases which have case coordinator assigned. Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: This report seems to depend on there being at least one role on the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on additional tests and comments from Demerit, it appears that the report requires the case manager to be assigned to the case to list the case.

The obvious workaround is to assign a case coordinator to a case and then everything seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the filters tab, my guess is one of two things:

1) A popup is appearing at the top right, like this

[image]

and maybe it's not clear what it's saying, but it's an error saying that if you have Staff Member and Relationship checked you need to select a relationship type on the Filters tab.

2) That theme is maybe shoreditch? It looks different from the standard so maybe something is going on there. If the problem isn't #1 above, then if you switch to the standard theme does it work?

Comment: 1) I get this one, but the list is still empty even if I deselect both fields

Comment: 2) I am using CiviCRM Admin Utilities for Wordpress, but the problem persists even if the plugin is disabled